# HeaderListView Incorret item access

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, header

I'm using [HeaderListView](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/) and I'm getting a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as expected when you try to access the position `-1` of any Array. But here goes my point, I'm getting this error inside the framework code, more precisely a this line:

```
boolean prevHasRows = mAdapter.numberOfRows(actualSection - 1) > 0;
```

inside the file [HeaderListView](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView/blob/master/HeaderListView/src/main/java/com/applidium/headerlistview/HeaderListView.java)

I tried to hack it and put something like:

```
boolean prevHasRows = mAdapter.numberOfRows(actualSection - 1) > 0;
```

Here I got no more `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but when I have a list big enough to scroll, the least items got messed, I got itens from the first section inside the last.

Here goes my the code:

Fragment where I setup the adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.soutsapp.souts.R;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.Menu;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.Product;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.model.modelview.OrderItem;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.userInterface.adapter.SectionAdapter;
import br.com.soutsapp.souts.userInterface.controls.HeaderListView;


public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
private Context mContext;
private List<OrderItem> itens;

private Menu menu;
public MenuFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    mContext = getContext();

    itens = new ArrayList<>();
    menu = new Menu();

    setUpCardListView(v);
    return v;
}

private void setUpCardListView(View v){
    HeaderListView list = (HeaderListView) v.findViewById(R.id.hlv_card_items);

    list.setAdapter(new SectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public int numberOfSections() {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().size();
        }

        @Override
        public int numberOfRows(int section) {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getRowItem(int section, int row) {
            return menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasSectionHeaderView(int section) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getRowView(final int section, final int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.menu_item_row), null);

                TextView tvMenuItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_menu_item_name);
                TextView tvMenuItemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);

                String itemName = menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).get(row).getName();
                tvMenuItemName.setText(itemName);

                String itemPrice = String.valueOf(menu.getMenuSessions().get(section).get(row).getPrice());
                tvMenuItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

                TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);

                tvQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) v;
                        Product product = (Product) getRowItem(section, row);

                        if (tvQuantity.getText().equals("1") && !tvQuantity.getText().equals("")){
                            tvQuantity.setText("");

                            OrderItem itenToRemove = null;
                            for(OrderItem item: itens){
                                if(item.getProductId() == product.getId()){
                                    itenToRemove = item;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            itens.remove(itenToRemove);
                        }
                        else{

                            for(OrderItem item: itens){
                                if(item.getProductId() == product.getId()){
                                    int quantity = item.getQuantity();
                                    item.setQuantity(--quantity);
                                    tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(getResources().getLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1), null);
            }

            switch (section) {
                case 0:
                    ((TextView) convertView).setText("Bebidas");
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue_Jay));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ((TextView) convertView).setText("Comidas");
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red_Wine));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((TextView) convertView).setText("Diversos");
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Camel_brown));
                    break;
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
            super.onRowItemClick(parent, view, section, row, id);

            TextView tvQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity);
            Product p = (Product) getRowItem(section, row);

            boolean exist = false;
            for(OrderItem item : itens){
                if(item.getProductId() == p.getId()){
                    int actualQuantity = item.getQuantity();
                    item.setQuantity(++actualQuantity);
                    tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            if(!exist){
                itens.add(new OrderItem(p.getId(), 1));
                tvQuantity.setText("1");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I solved it by modify the SectionAdapter.java

Like below:

```
public abstract int numberOfRows(int section);

public int numberOfRow(int section) {
    if(section < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return this.numberOfRows(section);
}
```

Then, in the HeaderListView that you had mentioned, modify it to call

```
boolean currIsLast = mAdapter.getRowInSection(realFirstVisibleItem) == mAdapter.numberOfRow(actualSection) - 1; 

boolean prevHasRows = mAdapter.numberOfRow(actualSection - 1) > 0;
```

Now we solve the bug.